# Calling a function in another contract (invalid checksum error)

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, contract-deployment

I know there are plenty of questions like this but I believe this is different.

Based on [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/call-function-on-another-contract?rq=1), I wrote this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Registry {
    mapping(string => address) ID;
    mapping(address => address) Contract;

    function addID(string _id, address publicAddress) {
        ID[_id] = publicAddress;
    }

    function addContract(address _owner) {
        Contract[_owner] = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract User {
    // The GMC contract
    address regAddress = 0xf70ce669d4fa2bdeae1c4c61021627fc4b1d463c;
    address owner = msg.sender;

    function addID(string _id){
        // Get the GMC contract
        Registry registry = Registry(regAddress);
        registry.addID(_id, owner);
    }

    function addContract(address _owner) {
        Registry registry = Registry(regAddress);
        registry.addContract(owner);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm 100% sure that the contract Registry has been mined at address `0xf70ce669d4fa2bdeae1c4c61021627fc4b1d463c`.

Pasting as is on Remix returns an error

`This looks like an address but has invalid checksum`

Following [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18973/smart-contract-address-checksum), I tried converting the address to upper case. That returns

`TypeError: Invalid literal value`

One suggestion in the question is to use import. I'm not doing that because of another (unanswered) question I asked [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23696/importing-a-contract-from-another-contract-in-nodejs-app) (can't use import when deploying with NodeJS).

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `address regAddress =0xF70ce669d4FA2BdEae1c4C61021627fC4b1d463C` and the error will be dismissed.

the trick is to use https://etherscan.io/ to give you back the address with the checksum.

Comment: The answer worked but could you explain why this is?